# Obtencion de datos de JCombobox

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Estoy generando un formulario donde necesito obtener cierto valor de un Jcombobox
actualmente, este es mi código:

```
private void llenarMatriz() {
    String cmb = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre_matriz FROM matriz ORDER BY nombre_matriz ASC";
      try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet set = st.executeQuery(cmb);
           while (set.next()) {
            cmbMatriz.addItem(set.getString("nombre_matriz"));
        } // cn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("error consulta");
    }
}
```

por lo que necesito ayuda en poder tomar la PRIMERA PALABRA del combobox es decir : "agua", "sedimentos" , "tejido"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me se una posible solución, lamentablemente es un poco larga, pero si te funciona, perfecto.
Para comenzar, necesitas una clase que incluya dos valores, el punto es que crees una lista con la palabra que comienza, ejemplo: "Agua de Mar" y su valor "Agua".

```
public class Tipo {
    private String nombre, valor;

    public Tipo(String nombre, String valor) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public void setValor(String valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

Lo importante de aquí es que el metodo toString() solo muestre el valor que quieras mostrar dentro del JComboBox, para que puedas crear varios objetos recomiendo utilizar un ArrayList y lo ingresamos con un for al JcomboBox

```
public class Valor extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox<Tipo> cbCaja; //Tiene que ser del mismo tipo que tu clase
    private JButton btnBoton;//El botón es solo para crear un evento
    private ArrayList<Tipo> lista; //La lista también debe ser del tipo de tu clase

    public Valor() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(100, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        //Aquí creo los objetos, pero en tu caso los puedes crear con Query
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Tipo("Agua de Mar", "Agua"));
        lista.add(new Tipo("Sedimiento Marino", "Sedimiento"));
        lista.add(new Tipo("Tejido Biologico", "Tejido"));

        cbCaja = new JComboBox<>();
        cbCaja.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);//Se agregan al combo
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            cbCaja.addItem(lista.get(i));
        }

        btnBoton = new JButton("Boton");
        btnBoton.setBounds(10, 100, 80, 20);
        btnBoton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
//En el evento obtengo el objeto seleccionado
                Tipo seleccionado = (Tipo) cbCaja.getSelectedItem();
//Para llamar el valor solo invocas el metodo .getValor()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""
                        + "El nombre: " + seleccionado.getNombre() + "\n"
                        + "El valor: " + seleccionado.getValor());
            }
        });
        add(btnBoton);
        add(cbCaja);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Valor v = new Valor();
    }
}
```

Se que es un poco extenso, pero es funcional.
Saludos